# pass variable to the user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have created an user control for cascading two dropdownlists "province" and "city". But everytime when I run it, the error message said "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred"
Here is my user control code

```
public partial class cascadingdropdownlist : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string province_selectedvalue
    {

        set
        {
            string province_selectedvalue = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return city_selectedvalue;
        }
    }

    public string city_selectedvalue
    {
        set
        {
            string city_selectedvalue = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return city_selectedvalue;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = province_selectedvalue;
        ............
    }
```

}

In the host page

```
<uc1:cascadingdropdownlist ID="province_city" runat="server" OnPreLoad="province_city_OnPreLoad"/>
```

The code behind is

```
protected void province_city_OnPreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        province_city.province_selectedvalue = myReader["Province/State"].ToString();
        province_city.city_selectedvalue = myReader["City"].ToString();
    }
```

The error happened in calling user control the province_selectedvalue.get method. why I don't understand why? Anyone can help me, thanks very much

Comment: But how to run the host page code first then load the user control to pass the variable value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your property:

```
public string city_selectedvalue 
{ 
    set 
    { 
        string city_selectedvalue = value; 
    }
```

Calls the setter (or the getter!) on city_selectedvalue over and over again resulting in a stack overflow.

Replace your property with this

```
public string city_selectedvalue { get; set; }
```

I also thought you could do the same with province_selectedvalue but its getter refers to city_selectedvalue - is that correct?

Comment: Indeed i think the problem is in the getter, because the setter does not call itself. Anyway using automatic property will solve the issue.

Comment: thanks, the error was gone, but there is another problem that I want to set the province_selectedvalue first in the host page using OnPreLoad (maybe another method). It seems it still load the user control first, so the value "province_selectedvalue" is empty

Comment: Ah, that likely has to do with the control vs. page lifecycle. A page's OnLoad event fires after a control's OnLoad so you have to account for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the code is in an infinitive loop. When you call province_selectedvalue.get you are calling city_selectedvalue get. And you have the same name for the property in the variable you think you are calling so it is calling the same over and over again.

Change you code to

```
public string city_selectedvalue { get; set; }
```

And

```
public string province_selectedvalue { get; set; }
```